Replacement crankset for a Specialized Sirrus X 3.0
I am looking for a replacement crankset for my Sirrus X 3.0, preferably a cheaper option.
The stock crankset appears to have a spindle diameter of 24mm, spindle length of 107mm and 40 teeth. I have never replaced a crankset before, are there any common issues with installing replacements?
Edit:
The reason I am replacing the crankset is because the pedal thread on the drive-side arm is worn down, and pedals won't attach properly.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It would help to know the goal of this; are you looking to change your gearing, the length of your cranks, or are there mechanical issues with your existing kit?

@DavidW Thank you! I made an edit to clarify my reason for replacing the crankset

Can you just indicate which version of the Sirrus you have and what rear derailleur you have?

Are you replacing because the chainring is worn out?
Your current drive train spec is:

Crankset: OEM Forged aluminum arms, 2-piece, 24mm spindle,
Chainrings: 1x 40T, 10 speed. Narrow-wide steel chainring.
Bottom Bracket: Threaded BSA 68mm, 24mm spindle.

From that spec you can hit your local internet bike shop and find something in your price range. Your local bike shop might even have what you need in the swaps bin or brand new.
Watch out that you get a narrow-wide chainring whatever you do. That’s a really important feature to keep the chain from dropping.
The chainrings look to be riveted on and thus not replaceable from the manufacturer photos but if that isn’t the case you can buy a new chainring and replace just that with not much than a couple of hex wrenches.
If you’re replacing either the entire crankset or just the chainring be aware that you’ll probably need to replace both cassette and chain at the same time which will add to your budget along with the tools to do the job.

If the chain ring is not worn out the chain and cassette likely does not need to be replaced.

Thank you for the elaborate answer! I am replacing the crankset due to a bad pedal thread on the drive-side arm. I am really just looking for a compatible crankset which will get my bike up and running. The branding on the stock crankset is supposedly FSA, and I have heard that these generally should be compatible with Shimano cranksets. Since I want to keep costs down, do you think it would be best to just purchase the stock FSA crankset? It goes for $200 ~ at my local reseller

@414Sigge I would personally go for a Shimano one. You may need to change the bottom bracket, but that's a $15 part. Note that my brother has a Sirrus X 5.0, and I have to say the bottom bracket situation is a bit strange: it's a 68mm BSA shell, but a Shimano MTB bottom bracket (mounted without spacers - MTB bottom brackets require a 73mm shell so additional spacers to work with a 68mm shell), and a FSA crankset.

Are helicoils reliable in a crank pedal thread interface? You could repair the thread if reliable enough otherwise that would just be wasted time any money.
